# What is the best way to set up multiple urls (axios) in Vuex Store?

Tags: vue.js, axios, vuex, nuxt.js

I have several pages that I want to retrieve, I have it working but notice that the page loads a bit slow while it is not much data.

How can I set my APIs in vuex store with axios so that it performs better.

Store:

```
export default {
    state: { 
    homepage: [],
    aboutUs: []
},


actions: {
  async loadPosts({ commit }) {
    // Define urls pages
    const urlHomepage = 'https://api.domain.com/homepage';
    const urlaboutUs = 'https://api.domain.com/aboutUs';

    // Responses pages
    const responseHomepage = await this.$axios.get(urlHomepage);
    const responseaboutUs = await this.$axios.get(urlaboutUs);

    // variables pages
    this.homepage = responseHomepage.data
    this.aboutUs = responseaboutUs.data

    // mutations pages
    commit('SET_HOMEPAGE', this.homepage)
    commit('SET_aboutUs', this.aboutUs)
  }
},

mutations: {
  SET_HOMEPAGE (state, homepage) {
    state.homepage = homepage;
  },
  SET_aboutUs (state, aboutUs) {
    state.aboutUs = aboutUs;
  }
}
};
```

And I use this in my page like:

```
import {mapState} from 'vuex';

export default {
  name: 'Home',
  mounted() {
    this.$store.dispatch('loadPosts')
  },
  computed: {
    ...mapState([
      'homepage'
    ])
  }
}
```

By adding:

```
{{homepage}}
```

Is there a better way to store multiple API urls? I'm using Nuxt.js.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could speed things up significantly (especially for more than 2 pages) by running the async calls simultaneously instead of running one only after the other is finished:

<sub>**Version 1**</sub>

```js
// Execute async immediately and store the promises
const pH = this.$axios.get(urlHomepage); 
const pA = this.$axios.get(urlaboutUs);

// Await them all at once instead of individually
const [rH, rA] = await Promise.all([pH, pA]);
```

Or another way of writing this:

<sub>**Version 2**</sub>

```js
const [rH, rA] = await Promise.all([
  this.$axios.get(urlHomepage),
  this.$axios.get(urlaboutUs)
]);
```

<sup>The results array order will be the same as the called order</sup>

Then store the results:

```js
// variables pages
this.homepage = rH.data
this.aboutUs = rA.data

// mutations pages
commit('SET_HOMEPAGE', this.homepage)
commit('SET_aboutUs', this.aboutUs)
```

Comment: This works, but is still slow in loading. The data jumps in after about 2 seconds

I see in the network tab of developer tools that the data is loading 3 times for each. Is there a way to import the mapstate from vuex in one file and define the mapstates in one file?

Currently I'm importing mapstate in each component where I need to use the data.

Comment: This just ensures that all async requests are made simultaneously, since you were waiting for each previous request to finish before starting the next one.  But if you're calling `loadPosts` 3 times that's a whole other problem.  Are you dispatching `loadPosts` in each component?  `mapState` in itself is harmless so no need to worry about consolidating that.

Comment: yes, I removed `loadPosts` now inside the components :) now it's loading 1 time, I'm dispatching `loadPosts` only in the pages now.